# Ray Tracing: Shadows from Multiple Lights

Tags: c++, shadow, raytracing, light

**[Edit] As is typical in programming, I figured it out shortly after posting! see my answer if you're interested :)**

I'm working on a ray tracer in C++ and wanted some help with something. I've got 2 lights in my scene, a point light and a directional light, and a bunch of spheres (along with a plane acting as the "floor").

If i run the ray tracer with either of the lights present (but the other light not present), it makes shadows as expected (see images below).

[Directional light shadows image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnc88.png)

[Point light shadows image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nBMl.png)

The trouble is, when I run my ray tracer with both lights present, only the point light shadows show up, I can tell the light is "on" because the scene is brighter:

See my code below for detecting shadows:

```
bool Scene::shadowtrace( Ray &ray, double t )
{
    Object *obj = obj_list;
    Light *lt = light_list;
    Vector v1, v2; // hit -> light vector
    Hit   hit;

    Vertex intersect = (ray.position( t ));
    intersect.plus( ray.D, -0.001 ); // offset  intersection ever so slightly away from object, to avoid self-shadowing
    v1.set( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    v2.set( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ); // initialise

    while (lt != (Light *)0)
    {
        Ray shadowRay;
        shadowRay.P = (intersect);

        Vertex lightPos = Vertex( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
        lt->getPosition( lightPos ); // sets value of lightPos

        if (lightPos.x > T_LIMIT) // If set absurdly high, we're dealing with a directional light
        {
            lt->getDirection( v1 ); // sets v1 to light direction (reversed)
            v1.normalise( );
            shadowRay.D = v1; // set hit-to-light vector as shadowray direction

            while (obj != (Object *)0)
            {
                if (obj->intersect( shadowRay, &hit ) == true)
                {
                    if (!((hit.t * hit.t) < 0.001)) // Self-shadow if very very small t number
                    {
                        return true; // ray hits an onject, and the object occurs before the light
                    }
                }
                obj = obj->next( );
            }
        }
        else    // otherwise, it's a point light :)
        {
            v1 = (lightPos.minus( intersect )); // find vector from intersection to light
            v2 = v1; // keep un-normalised version for preventing mis-shadowing from objects behind the light source
            v1.normalise( );
            shadowRay.D = v1; // set ray direction to hit-to-light vector

            while (obj != (Object *)0)
            {
                if (obj->intersect( shadowRay, &hit ) == true)
                {
                    if (!((hit.t * hit.t) > (v2.lengthSq( ))))  // Check hit.t against magnitude of (un-normalised) intersection-to-light vector
                        if (!((hit.t * hit.t) < 0.001)) // Self-shadow if very very small t number
                        { // Used hit.t^2 to avoid having to SQRT the length. Is acceptable for comparisons
                            return true; // ray hits an onject, and the object occurs before the light
                        }

                }

                obj = obj->next( );
            }
        }

        lt = lt->next( );
    }

    return false;
}
```

If a shadow is detected, only ambient light is attributed to the point, otherwise ambient + diffuse is attributed (I haven't gotten round to adding specular yet).

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: (Link for the output with both lights [https://puu.sh/ui6Ka/e81edc5f6e.jpg] - because SO only lets me post 2 links in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm folks! 
I Figured it out!!

before each object list loop I added:

```
obj = obj_list;
```

to reset to the first object, this solved the problem :)